# How to panelize gerber files?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, altium, gerber, panelize

I am planning on ordering a panel with four different designs on it. Two were made in Altium, while the other two were made in Eagle.

Altium has a great tool for panelizing boards designed in it, but I don't believe it can put designs from other programs on the panel.

How can I panelize these PCBs?

Comment: The manufacturer that I ordered PCB printing did not accept different designs on the same panel (probably because they wanted me to pay for each design separately). Just ask your manufacturer if they accept it. If you do not have special requirements about the edges of the board, the manufacturer can panelize it for you at their own convenience.

Comment: you can generate all files into Gerber files and combine it or take the advice from Naz. Ask your own PCB fabricator if they are willing to take 4 boards in one panel. If it is a sample order just for test, leave it to your fabricator who can make it by their own .Anyway, A good communication with the vendor is a good choice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use the open source utility GerbMerge, it gets the job done nicely. The utility can be found [here](http://www.gedasymbols.org/user/stefan_tauner/tools/gerbmerge/doc/#Running)

Edit: looks like there is another version here that could be more up-to-date: https://github.com/provideyourown/gerbmerge

Comment: Here is a great explanation of what to do : https://radrajith.github.io/gerbmerge/
But I advise you to have a try to Gerber Panelizer : https://github.com/ThisIsNotRocketScience/GerberTools

Answer (score 5):

I use [ThisIsNotRocketScience Gerber Panelizer](http://blog.thisisnotrocketscience.nl/projects/pcb-panelizer/) software. It works very well, is open-source, so I can fix edge case bugs myself if necessary, have made and ordered at least 5 different panels with it, without any problems. [Here's a tutorial](https://hackaday.io/project/19202/log/59210) on this software I wrote on this some time ago.

Comment: Just experienced this and it is really great even if these's some little bugs.
This big advantage is that there's a graphical user interface (seems GerbMerge do not have).